# Is it right to model a binary response variable on a set of variables, where one of the explanatory variables is assumed dependent on the others?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity, bivariate

I am modeling the binary variable Y on a set of variables, say the vector X, using logistic regression. Then, I want to model another binary variable, Z, again on vector X plus Y. Is this theoretically right (since Y is assumed dependent on X)? I know one alternative approach is using a bivariate logistic regression, with Y and Z as the response variables, but I basically cannot do that, because it just makes sense to model Z on a subset of the data, not the whole data, while Y needs to use the whole data.

Comment: as the question body is written Y is not 'assumed dependent on X', rather it is entirely and simply a transformation of X, making it completely dependent, no assumption needed. This doesn't affect that applicability of Ben's answer as a transformed version can be beneficial since regression models only transform variables as weighted sums (or products if including interaction terms) and so transformation of variables allows other mathematical combinations to be tested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regression models do not assume independence of the explanatory variables, so it is perfectly legitimate to use a logistic regression with one explanatory variable that is dependent on another.  The issue of statistical dependence between explanatory variables is called **multicollinearity**, and it affects the results of your model, but does not invalidate it.  Multicollinearity between explanatory variables in your model means that there is some redundancy in the information provided by those explanatory variables.

Bear in mind that if you are ultimately looking for the joint distribution of $Y,Z \bot \boldsymbol{X}$ then you will have to be careful getting this.  It is not easy to put separate regression models together to estimate joint behaviour, and so you may be better off using a single model that treats $(Y, Z)$ as your response.  Since you are working with two binary response variables, your problem could be handled by using a [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) with four outcome possibilities; this analysis can be conducted in `R` using the [`multinom` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nnet/versions/7.3-12/topics/multinom)  in the `nnet` package.

Comment: So the problem with the bivariate model (assuming joint distribution) is only that it is not easy to implement or theoretically you don't recommend its use?

Comment: It depends what you are using it *for*.  If you are not interested in the joint conditional distribution of $Y,Z | \boldsymbol{X}$ then you can stick with the bivariate model.  If you *are* interested in this joint distribution, I would recommend the multinomial logistic model, treating your response as a four-category outcome giving each possible combination of the two binary response variables.